# Increasing timeout period for schema compare

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio

I need to increase the timeout period for schema comparison.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to compare two SQL Server 2008 R2 databases on Windows Server 2008.

I believe this is something I need to set in the Windows registry but I can't find where.

Comment: Is the database restored from different server and then you are doing the schema comparision ?

Answer (score 7):

You have to increase the query timeout allowed on the connection. Unfortunately there is no user-interface-exposed way to do this. You have to search the Windows Registry for the key "QueryTimeoutSeconds" and increase the value. I increased mine from 60 to 360 and that made my schema compare timeouts disappear in Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: See here for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833294(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2

Answer (score 3):

Advanced settings in connection has that ability

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust this setting by opening your schema comparison and editing the connection which is timing out (source or target). Click the `Advanced` button and set the `Connect Timeout` property to a higher value than the default of `15`.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information and possibly a screen shot or two?

Comment: This setting didn't work for me. I believe there needs to be another settings for the query timeout (vs. connect timeout) not sure though...